# Able to authenticate with DocuSign PHP SDK, but createEnvelope method fails ('[400] Error connecting to the API')

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am attempting to send an envelope to a user like so:

```
$envelope_status = $this->envelopeApi->createEnvelope($this->accountId, $envelope, null);
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception: exception 'DocuSign\eSign\ApiException' with message '[400] Error connecting to the API (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1687539/envelopes)' in /srv/www/vhosts/redacted/pages/test/docusign/sdk/docusign-php-client-master/src/ApiClient.php:250
```

Note that I am able to successfully poll the API for my Account ID after having successfully logged in, so the problem must lie elsewhere. I am attaching a link to a var_dump() of the $envelope [here](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8875850). I suspect I must be messing up one of the steps creating the envelope.

Thank you!

EDIT: for reference this is where I was messing up. When $index == 0, setDocumentId() would fail - Document IDs start at 1.

```
function addDocument($fileTitle, $fileContent)
{
    $index = count($this->documents);
    $this->documents[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
    $this->documents[$index]->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode($fileContent));
    $this->documents[$index]->setName($fileTitle);
    $this->documents[$index]->setDocumentId($index + 1);
    return json_encode($this->documents[$index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out -  I was setting my documentID (`DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document()`) to 0 when it should have been 1. That resolved the issue!

Comment: Can you show me the code snippet where you set the documentID to 1 instead of 0?